# D3 js filter select

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, data-driven

I dont knoe exactly what is going on here tried everything to no success, here is my code, i am trying to add color by changing the opacity with the rgba, but i noticed only the first element of the selected(this) is being given the rgba and the rest turns to rgb, please note am talking about the line of that has the `` style('fill',`rgba(${red}, ${green}, ${blue}, ${i+1 * 0.25}`) ``

````
        currentEl.filter(function(d, i, n):any {
            if(bottonValue==='filter-odd') {
                if(i % 2 === 0) {
                    select(this).style('fill',`rgba(${red}, ${green}, ${blue}, ${i+1 * 0.25}`)
                }
                else {
                    select(this).style('fill','rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.5)')
                }
            }
            else if(bottonValue==='filter-even') {
                if(i % 2 !== 0) {
                    select(this).style('fill',`rgba(${red}, ${green}, ${blue}, ${i+1 * 0.25}`,)
                }
                else {
                    select(this).style('fill','rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.5)')
                }
            }
            else
                select(this).style('fill',`rgba(${red}, ${green}, ${blue}, ${i+1 * 0.25}`)
           
        }) 
    }```

below is my code 


[![dom and result image][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhhtW.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved with the help from discord, i needed to add `(i+1)` and not `i+1`

```
select(this).style('fill',`rgba(${red}, ${green}, ${blue}, ${(i+1) * 0.25}`,)
```